# django-attachments like pluggable app for images

Tags: django

I'm looking for a django-attachments like pluggable app where I can attach images to model instances.

I have looked at django-photologue, but that looks like its more for building either a site gallery or user galleries.

I'd like something like django-attachments, forms for adding, and template tags for deleting attachments, except more specifically for images. The ability to attach comments to images would be a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageKit](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit) is more for image processing than just storing, but it might work depending on your needs.